# Variance of Rao Blackwellization for Monte Carlo Estimate of Expectation

Tags: monte-carlo, rao-blackwell

from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.0118.pdf

If we have a function $J(X,Y)$ of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and we want to compute the expectation $\mathbb E_{p(X,Y)}[J(X,Y)]$.

We define $\hat J(X)= \mathbb E_{p(Y)}[J(X,Y)\mid X]$.

Note that: $$\mathbb E_{p(X,Y)}[J(X,Y)] = \mathbb E_{p(X)} [\hat J(X)]$$

So we can use $\hat J(X)$ instead of $J(X, Y)$ in a Monte-Carlo Estimate.

For the variance holds (variance reduction)
$$
var(\hat J(X)) = var(J(X,Y)) - \mathcal E[(J(X,Y) - \hat J(X))^2]
$$

Here I have two questions:

- How can we proof that (variance reduction)? In the paper no proof is given.

Thanks.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about your second question so I can improve my answer to your question?

Comment: Thank you very much. I finally got it. So the second question is not important any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variance reduction follows from the [the law of total variance](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-012-introduction-to-probability-spring-2018/part-i-the-fundamentals/MITRES_6_012S18_L13AS.pdf). Suppose that $W,Z$ are two random variables, then it follows that
$$
\mathbb{V}(W)=\mathbb{V}(\mathbb{E}(W\vert Z))+\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{V}(W\vert Z))
$$
then, replace $W$ by $J(X,Y)$ and $\mathbb{E}(W\vert Z)$ by $\hat{J}(X)$ and we obtain:
$$
\mathbb{V}(J(X,Y))=\mathbb{V}(\hat{J}(X))+\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{V}(J(X,Y)\vert X))
$$
Notice that the second summand on the right hand side is given by
$$\mathbb{V}(J(X,Y)\vert X)=\mathbb{E}(J(X,Y)^2\vert X)-(\mathbb{E}J(X,Y)\vert X)^2=\mathbb{E}(J(X,Y)^2\vert X)-\hat{J}(X)^2
$$
plug into the ANOVA identity, solve with respect to $\mathbb{V}(\hat{J}(X)$ to obtain
$$
\mathbb{V}(\hat{J}(X)=\mathbb{V}(J(X,Y))-\left(\mathbb{E}(J(X,Y)^2)-\mathbb{E}(\hat{J}(X)^2)\right)=\mathbb{V}(J(X,Y))-\mathbb{E}\left(\left(J(X,Y)-\hat{J}(X)\right)^2\right)
$$
as desired.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have not [read the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.0118.pdf) but the variance reduction provided by an iid sample is obvious from the variance Pythagorean decomposition and less obvious for a two-stage Gibbs sampler ([Liu, Wong & Kong, 1994](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article/81/1/27/252043)). For a general MCMC chain there is no reason to see variance reduction due to the correlation between the elements of the chain ([Liu, Wong & Kong, 1995](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2337047)).