# Variance of Rao Blackwellization for MC Estimate of Expectation

Tags: monte-carlo, rao-blackwell

from https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0118

If we have a function $J(X,Y)$ of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and we want to compute the expectation $\mathbb E_{p(X,Y)}[J(X,Y)]$.

We define $\hat J(X)= \mathbb E_{p(Y)}[J(X,Y)\mid X]$.

Note that: $$\mathbb E_{p(X,Y)}[J(X,Y)] = \mathbb E_{p(X)} [\hat J(X)]$$

So we can use $\hat J(X)$ instead of $J(X, Y)$ in a Monte-Carlo Estimate.

For the variance holds (variance reduction)
$$
var(\hat J(X)) = var(J(X,Y)) - \mathcal E[(J(X,Y) - \hat J(X))^2]
$$

Here I have one questions:

- How can we prove that (variance reduction)? In the paper, no proof is given.

Here is one proof of this question (from [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381518/variance-of-rao-blackwellization-for-monte-carlo-estimate-of-expectation/381539#381539)):

The variance reduction follows from the [the law of total variance](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-012-introduction-to-probability-spring-2018/part-i-the-fundamentals/MITRES_6_012S18_L13AS.pdf). Suppose that $W,Z$ are two random variables, then it follows that
$$
\mathbb{V}(W)=\mathbb{V}(\mathbb{E}(W\vert Z))+\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{V}(W\vert Z))
$$
then, replace $W$ by $J(X,Y)$ and $\mathbb{E}(W\vert Z)$ by $\hat{J}(X)$ and we obtain:
$$
\mathbb{V}(J(X,Y))=\mathbb{V}(\hat{J}(X))+\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{V}(J(X,Y)\vert X))
$$
Notice that the second summand on the right hand side is given by
$$\mathbb{V}(J(X,Y)\vert X)=\mathbb{E}(J(X,Y)^2\vert X)-(\mathbb{E}J(X,Y)\vert X)^2=\mathbb{E}(J(X,Y)^2\vert X)-\hat{J}(X)^2
$$
plug into the ANOVA identity, solve with respect to $\mathbb{V}(\hat{J}(X)$ to obtain
$$
\mathbb{V}(\hat{J}(X))=\mathbb{V}(J(X,Y))-\left(\mathbb{E}(J(X,Y)^2)-\mathbb{E}(\hat{J}(X)^2)\right)=\mathbb{V}(J(X,Y))-\mathbb{E}\left(\left(J(X,Y)-\hat{J}(X)\right)^2\right)
$$
as desired.

======================== end proof ==========================

But the can't follow the idea of the last line:
$$
\mathbb{V}(J(X,Y))-\left(\mathbb{E}(J(X,Y)^2)-\mathbb{E}(\hat{J}(X)^2)\right)=\mathbb{V}(J(X,Y))-\mathbb{E}\left(\left(J(X,Y)-\hat{J}(X)\right)^2\right)
$$
why the following equality holds?
$$
\mathbb{E}(J(X,Y)^2)-\mathbb{E}(\hat{J}(X)^2) = \mathbb{E}\left(\left(J(X,Y)-\hat{J}(X)\right)^2\right)
$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another form of answer can be the following, based on the proof outlined in the post you've linked:

If you open up the square form:
$$\mathbb E[(J(X,Y)-\hat J(X))^2]=\mathbb E[J(X,Y)^2]-2\mathbb E[J(X,Y)\hat J (X)]+\mathbb E[\hat J(X)^2]$$

The middle term can be written as (using [Law of Total Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)):

$$\mathbb E[J(X,Y)\hat J (X)]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[J(X,Y)\hat J (X)|X]]=\mathbb E[\hat J(X)\mathbb E[J(X,Y)|X]]=\mathbb E[\hat J(X)^2]$$

When substituted, you've the equality.

Answer (score 1):

The Pythagorean decomposition of the variance
$$\mathbb{V}(W)=\mathbb{V}(\mathbb{E}(W\vert Z))+\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{V}(W\vert Z))$$
shows that the original variance is a sum of two positive terms, hence
$$\mathbb{V}(W)\ge\mathbb{V}(\mathbb{E}(W\vert Z))$$
showing that both versions have the same expectation and that the conditional expectation has a smaller variance.